# Button press method not reading latest EditText data

Tags: android, variables, methods, android-edittext

I'm working on an `EditText` where the user needs to insert a number of 8 digits on an `EditText` and when he inserts it, the app shows a dialog in order to confirm it where he can accept or cancel it.

The problem is that for this dialog message it only takes the number inserted for the first time so if the user changes the number the dialog is always the same.

For example: the user introduces 12345678 and the dialog message says "...12345678". But if the user changes now the number for example 98765432 the message is still "...12345678".

Here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
   {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.identificacion);
      Button bSiguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_siguiente);
     dniText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dni_candidato);





bSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

  //  try{


   //     catch (NumberFormatException e)
   //   //  {
        //  }
   user = Integer.parseInt(dniText.getText().toString());
     String longitud = dniText.getText().toString();
     DNIWord(user);

     if(longitud.length()==8){
         showDialog(DIALOG_CONFIRMAR_CANDIDATO);
     }
     else{
         showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR_DNI);

     }

    }
```

});

}

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id){

     switch (id) {
     case DIALOG_CONFIRMAR_CANDIDATO:
           return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_warning)
               .setTitle(R.string.confirmardni)
               .setMessage("Tu DNI es "  +DNIWord(user)+  " ?")
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                       Intent i = new Intent(Ident.this,Autorizacion.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                    }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                   }
               })

               .create();

     case DIALOG_ERROR_DNI:
           return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error)
               .setTitle(R.string.error)
               .setMessage(R.string.errordni)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }
               })

               .create();
}

    return null;


}
 public static String DNIWord(int user) {
     user = Integer.parseInt(dniText.getText().toString());
      return (String.valueOf(user)   + "-"+   NIF_STRING_ASOCIATION.charAt(user % 23));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCreateDialog(int id) is called only once when the dialog of specific id is created. Once the  dialog is created, the method is never invoked for the same id.

In order to solve your problem, you have to additionally override onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) method. The method is invoked EVERYTIME before the dialog is shown.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog(int, android.app.Dialog)

You may amend your code as follows.

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    if (id == DIALOG_CONFIRMAR_CANDIDATO) {
        ((AlertDialog)dialog).setMessage("MESSAGE TO BE SHOWN");
    }
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I will check the link carefullty and try this. Thank you